# How can I alter a DIV so that I can click on the elements behind it?

Tags: css

I am creating something for a charity.  It is a house with bricks.  You donate money, click on a brick and you have a chance at a prize.

My problem is with the way I am using a DIV to place a door over the bricks.  The DIV is covering all of the bricks to the right of it and they are not clickable.  I am not sure how I can change it so that I have access to the bricks behind the door DIV down at the bottom.

Here is a working URL: http://matrixaccelerator.com/house2.php

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>House</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rewriteTag($x,$y,$brick) {
        alert("Buy/Bought");
        document.getElementById($x+','+$y).innerHTML = "<img src='images/brick"+$brick+".png'>";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/roof1.png" /><br />
<?php 
for ($y=1; $y <= 20; $y++) {
    if ((floor($y/2)) == ($y/2)) {
        $brickID = rand(1,3);
        echo "<img src='images/brick".$brickID."halfleft.png' style='padding-left:9px;'>";
    }
    for ($x=1; $x <= 20; $x++) {
        $brickID = rand(1,3);
        $freeSpaces = array('9,4','10,4','11,4','10,5','11,5','12,5','9,6','10,6','11,6','10,7','11,7','12,7','9,8','10,8','11,8','10,9','11,9','12,9','9,10','10,10','11,10','10,11','11,11','12,11','9,12','10,12','11,12','10,13','11,13','12,13','9,14','10,14','11,14','10,15','11,15','12,15','9,16','10,16','11,16','10,17','11,17','12,17','9,18','10,18','11,18','10,19','11,19','12,19','9,20','10,20','11,20');
        if (in_array($x.','.$y, $freeSpaces)) {
            $grey = "";
            echo "<span id='".$x.",".$y."'><img src='images/brick".$brickID.$grey.".png''".(((floor($y/2) <> $y/2) && ($x == 1)) ? 'style=\'padding-left:9px;\'' : '')."></span>";
        } else {
            $grey = "grey";
            echo "<span id='".$x.",".$y."'><img src='images/brick".$brickID.$grey.".png' onmouseover='this.src=\"images/brick".$brickID.".png\"' onmouseout='this.src=\"images/brick".$brickID."grey.png\"' onclick='rewriteTag(".$x.",".$y.",".$brickID.");'".(((floor($y/2) <> $y/2) && ($x == 1)) ? 'style=\'padding-left:9px;\'' : '')."></span>";
        }
    }
    if ((floor($y/2)) <> ($y/2)) {
        $brickID = rand(1,3);
        echo "<img src='images/brick".$brickID."halfright.png'>";
    }
    echo "<br>\n";
}
?>
<div style="position:relative;top:-239px;right:-395px;"><img src="images/door.png"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper of the door-image has no width, so it goes until the right border. Add `width:108px;` (size of the door-image) to the style attributes of this wrapper.

```
<div style="position:relative;top:-239px;right:-395px;width:108px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `width:108px;` to the style of the door div.

```
<div style="position:relative;top:-239px;right:-395px; width:108px;"><img src="images/door.png"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, edited your answer instead of mine, I did a rollback to your version.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your div is stretching out too far to the right. You can see this easily if you add a border to it, like this:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:-239px;right:-395px; border:solid 2px red;">
```

[image]

Too fix it, just set an appropriate width for it:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:-239px; right:-395px; width:108px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative CSS, that uses `display:inline-block` instead of `width`. I also switched the *negative right* to *positive left* offset, since it felt cleaner.

```
position: relative;
top: -239px;
left: 395px;
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Too fix it, just set an appropriate width for it:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:-239px; right:-395px; width:108px;">
```